# function code for TListbox and TCheckListbox

Tags: delphi

I want to create a function which should give a support to TListbox or TChecklistBox as a calling parameter

```
 MyUISupportFunction ( ......  ; aListBox : TObject);


 if (aListBox as  TObject) is TListBox  then (aListBox as  TListbox).Items.Clear;
 if (aListBox as  TObject) is TCHeckListBox  then (aListBox as  TCheckListbox).Items.Clear;
```

I wonder I  could write my code working on both UI (TListBox and TChechecklist Box) more efficient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both inherit from TCustomListBox

```
Procedure MyUISupportFunction (aListBox : TCustomListBox);
begin
   aListBox.Items.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyUISupportFunction(Listbox1);
  MyUISupportFunction(CheckListBox1);
end;
```

Comment: MyUISupportFunction ( ...... ; aListBox : TCustomListBox); and do a object cast before calling ?

Comment: -----   need to check ----